# HTML button is not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following html:

```
<div class="art-vmenublock-body">
    <MAP NAME="map1">
    <a HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape=RECT COORDS="30,262,180,300"></a>
    <a HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape=RECT COORDS="220,262,365,303"></a>
    <a HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape=RECT COORDS="405,262,560,303"></a>
    <a HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape=RECT COORDS="595,262,750,303"></a>
    <a HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape=RECT COORDS="790,262,940,296"></a>
    </MAP>
<IMG SRC="images/plans.png" BORDER=0 WIDTH=966 HEIGHT=343 USEMAP="#map1"></div>
```

And while I submit the button with name Buy now. 
It is working in Firefox.
But this process is not working in chrome,Internet Explorer
Let me know the reason.Please Help

Comment: Provide more details, like code snippets, markup etc.

Comment: @user1487499 : Next time, paste the code, select it, and press `CTRL+K`. And welcome to SO :)

Comment: You have markup errors, the `<map>` don't use `<a>` tags, it has own tags `<area>`

Comment: Can you show where is the `Buy Now` button in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. Your actual code is all messed up.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/UJCuT/

```
<div class="art-vmenublock-body">
    <img src="http://www.dailyencouragement.net/dmr/quarry_road_entrance_wall.jpg" BORDER="0" WIDTH="966" HEIGHT="343" usemap="#map1" />
    <map name="map1">
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="30,262,180,300" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="220,262,365,303" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="405,262,560,303" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="595,262,750,303" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="790,262,940,296" />
    </map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have markup errors, the `<map>` don't use `<a>` tags, it has own tags `<area>`, so your markup should look like this:

```
<div class="art-vmenublock-body">       
    <MAP name="map1">
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="30,262,180,300" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="220,262,365,303" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="405,262,560,303" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="595,262,750,303" />
        <area HREF="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal" shape="rect" coords="790,262,940,296" />
    </MAP>
    <IMG SRC="images/plans.png" BORDER=0 WIDTH=966 HEIGHT=343 USEMAP="#map1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For submit button to work. You need to enclose all the tags inside the FORM element.

Firefox some how understands it. Make sure you have a form tag

Comment: What happened to the comment entered here?? Why was it removed?